# Aurelia Composition

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to create some composition but I am not getting anything I'd expect. In almost every instance I've tried a similar setup I get something different which is wrong so this [GistRun](https://gist.run/?id=f41512a9918c7cd46cc948c0f5c0bf03) is representative only as far as it illustrates that at least "something" is wrong.

I've searched high and low for more information on the specific functionality and syntax of [compose](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/10/aurelia-dynamic-composition/) but I can't seem to solve the issues.

In the before mentioned GistRun you can see that the Container element is not rendered correctly, the `h1` is not rendered and that `@containerless` is being ignored.

In similar scenarios I've had `containerless` ignored on the `compose` element resulting in the rendering being ignored and I've had the entire thing not working with named slots.

I have a feeling that I'm doing something wrong and I can't quite figure out what it is. If someone knows what I'm doing wrong or can point me to a solution I would be much obliged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the reason things aren't working as you expect is that your gist is based off of a very old version of the framework. I've updated your gist to the latest version of Jeremy Danyow's Aurelia bundle here: https://gist.run/?id=1b304bb0c6dc98b23f4a3994acc280e4 The old version of the framework you were using in your gist still used the `content` element for content projection.

There are a couple of reasons your gist wouldn't run (aside from what I mentioned above). First, the `compose` element (and any custom elements you create) are not self-closing. This is per the Custom Element spec. So `<compose view="test.html" />` wont' work. Second, there is an existing issue regarding containerless elements being used with content projection. After talking with the team, this issue is unlikely to be resolved as containerless custom elements aren't really supported by the Shadow DOM v1 spec. If you remove the `containerless` attribute from the `compose` element, your demo works. Finally, you forgot to add `<require from="container"></require>` at the top of your `app.html` file. Thus Aurelia was unaware that `<ck-container>` is an Aurelia custom element. Unless you have globally registered a custom element (or any other view resource), you MUST `require` it in to any view where you wish to use it.

Now, let's discuss the use of `containerless`. The `containerless` decorator and attribute shouldn't be used simply to "clean up" your HTML. They should only be used when *absolutely necessary* to achieve your goals. "Making my HTML pretty" is never *absolutely necessary*. When you use `containerless` you are creating a custom element that likely cannot ever be used as a standard custom element. Again, the Aurelia team discourages you from using containerless elements unless necessary.

An example of a valid reason to use `containerless` is expained in our documentation here: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/4

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I now have a better understanding of `containerless`. I'm not really using it to clean up the code but I dynamically add these children to a flexbox and the  `compose` element was making me feel uncomfortable. About the registration: I thought I registered the component globally through the `index.html` with `.globalResources('container');` About the self-closing: *slaps head* I knew that, was a trial I forgot to clean up. Thank you again for the answer and if I ever get my idea working I'll post it!

Comment: You're totally right on the `globalResources('container')` thing. I deleted that without even looking when I saw you were using an old version of the framework. Sorry about that.